How to Remove this Old Faux Fireplace
I'm trying to figure out what's going on with the old fake fireplace. I'm trying to remove it from my wall, but after taking the plunge saw to the edges and removing the caulking between it and the wall, it still isn't budging.
For more information, the house was built in Edmonton Canada in 1953. The walls around the fireplace are drywall, which might be newer because the inside of the fireplace, and other areas of the house (the bedrooms) have plaster and metal lath. There are electrical outlets inside and above the fireplace.
Also note, our home inspection says there isn't any asbestos anywhere, just in case you were going to mention that haha 
The top of the fireplace is also wood, and we tried plunge sawing all the way around the perimeter of it and it won't budge. I've tried looking everywhere I can for info on this type of fireplace, but every search inevitably takes me to info about real, wood or gas fireplace. This is just a hunk of stone and wood stapled to my wall somehow.
Edit: some photos!




Pictures will help, but quite sure it attached to the wall and floor with nails.

Gotcha, thanks for the reminder, I meant to do this when I got home. I'm sure there are nails, I'm just not sure where to cut

I see expanded metal lath in your second picture.  Looks like you're going to have to cut through that in order to get the thing out of there.  Sawzall with a metal cutting blade.  Once that's cut then you should be able to use a sledge hammer.

From my comment below: This was quite the journey, but what I eventually discovered was the whole fireplace and the wall behind it was plaster. The corners of the fireplace used metal lath, but the rest of the wall is drywall-backed with plaster on top. Apparently, hybrid drywall/plaster, with gypsum as the backing and plaster on top, was a thing in the early 50's when they were transitioning away from plaster. Got it all down and out, and now I'm just drywalling the hole!

Are you saying that thing was framed and plastered along with the wall? Did they even have faux fireplaces back then? Seems crazy.

Yeah, it was! Entirely with plaster. I have the deconstructed bits in contractor bags from home depot haha. It does seem crazy, but I can't imagine it wasn't original with the house, with the way it integrated into the original hardwood floor. There's no chimney on that side (it's in the middle of the house), and the wall would be too thin for one anyways. According to wikipedia, the first electric fireplace was made in 1912, so it's not out of the realm of possibility that's what was meant to be there.

How much if it is stone? If it's cinder blocks or similar, you may need sledge and cold chisel to break it down for removal.
I'd start by trying to take the mantelpiece off and hope looking down into it answers some questions. Also, look for brackets or screws from inside the arch.

I mean, it looks like cinder blocks, so I'm not sure how much it'd budge if the blocks are still grouted together, right?  Destructive removal looks like the way to go—it's not like the CMUs are gonna be reusable here.

Building a fake fireplace out of cinder blocks would strike me as massive (literally) overkill, but that doesn't guarantee someone didn't do it.

Though the metal lath in the photo does suggest this may just be a plaster extension of the wall detailed to look like block. In which case, yes, reciprocating saw could be the right tool.

This was quite the journey, but what I eventually discovered was the whole fireplace and the wall behind it was plaster. The corners of the fireplace used metal lath, but the rest of the wall is drywall-backed with plaster on top. Apparently, hybrid drywall/plaster, with gypsum as the backing and plaster on top, was a thing in the early 50's when they were transitioning away from plaster. Got it all down and out, and now I'm just drywalling the hole!

@JackSchaible: You might want to post that as the Answer to your question. (Yes, you are allowed to answer your own questions.)
